# Delete Telegram None Admin Super Group

Tags: admin, telegram, account

I create a telegram supergroup and add some user to this group and after 2 days I delete my account, now I can not delete this group. Please help me.

Comment: Is this question about the [Telegram wiki](https://telegram.wiki/generalfaq/supergroups)?

Comment: hi, No about telegram social network

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't delete group