# How to delete Telegram Group

Tags: telegram

How to delete a Telegram Group that I just created?

Note, it about deleting a Telegram Group, not

- [Delete Message from Telegram Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770316/)
- [Delete Telegram None Admin Super Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491855/)
- [Remove image/message from a telegram group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003453/)

etc. thx.

Comment: You should ask Support instead of asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of Telegram X on Android, as of June 1st 2020, you can go to Manage Group (the pencil icon) -> 3 Dots -> Destroy Group

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

In the newer version, I find out there is no supergroup so simply go to manage group and set chat history to visible and confirm.
You can delete the group after that.